# Google IOS analytics [GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-analytics

Integrate google analytics in my application successfully. Got one waring in my console **[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:]**

**[GAI trackerWithName:trackingId:] (GAI.m:155): Nil or empty name supplied. Cannot create tracker.**

how can Fix this issues. Checked some solution in stack overflow but Cant get proper solution. Here Using code

In Appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"%@",[paths objectAtIndex:0]);

    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    [[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@""];
    [GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker = tracker;
return YES;
}
```

In viewcontroller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 self.screenName=@"My Screen";
}
```

help me how to fix this issues. Thanks advance.

Comment: can you explain `Got one waring in my console` what the warinig u get '

Comment: [GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002 this waring got anna..

Comment: ARE YOU PASSED THE TRACKING ID IN HERE  id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@""];

Comment: @add the tracking ID an check once bro